# Logistic Regression with scikit-learn giving key error while printing output

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use logistic regression to classify message into 'spam' or 'ham'. I used data source from [http://archive.ics.uci.edu/
ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/%20ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection) 
And I found that TFIDF is the right way to get features from text so I used the TfidfVectorizer from scikit learn and here is my code :

```
msg_df = pd.read_csv('data/sms', delimiter='\t', header = None)

X_train_data, X_test_data, y_train_data, y_test_data = train_test_split(msg_df[1],msg_df[0])

sms_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_vector = sms_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_data)
X_test_vector = sms_vectorizer.transform(X_test_data)

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train_vector, y_train_data)

sms_predictions = classifier.predict(X_test_vector)

print sms_predictions
for i, prediction in enumerate(sms_predictions[:5]):
    print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (prediction, X_test_data[i])
```

### When I run the code, following error occurs :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-b5f57158f320> in <module>()
      4 print sms_predictions
      5 for i, prediction in enumerate(sms_predictions[:5]):
----> 6     print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (prediction, X_test_data[i])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    555     def __getitem__(self, key):
    556         try:
--> 557             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    558 
    559             if not np.isscalar(result):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   1788 
   1789         try:
-> 1790             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
   1791         except KeyError as e1:
   1792             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3204)()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2903)()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3843)()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/hashtable.so in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6525)()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/hashtable.so in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6463)()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Could you upload your code to websites like https://ideone.com/ so we can get a fully runable code to inspect?

Comment: I think you're trying to enumerate i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and when you try to look up `X_test_data[1]`, it's not there because it's in `X_train_data[1]`. This has to do with how `train_test_split` splits your data randomly.

Comment: KeyError: 0, there is no "0"

Answer (score 2):

Start with this:

```
print sms_predictions
for i, prediction in enumerate(sms_predictions[:5]):
    print i,  prediction
    #print 'Prediction: %s. Message: %s' % (prediction, X_test_data[i])
```